# How to make it display the second largest value rather than lowest value

Tags: c, variables

Actually, I have to display the value of two highest grades but when I execute it shows the two highest value twice. So where is my error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float a,b,c,d=0,L,H;
    printf("Enter number of students:");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    for (a=1; a<=b; a++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter test score for student No.%.f:",a);
        scanf("%f",&c);
        if(c>=35)
            printf("Test score: %.f Grade: A\n",c);
        else if(c>=35)
            printf("Test score: %.f Grade: B\n",c);
        else if(c>=15)
            printf("Test score: %.f Grade: C\n",c);
        else if(c>=8)
            printf("Test score: %.f Grade: F\n",c);
        d=d+c;
    }
    printf("\nThe Average of the %.f score(s) is: %.2f\n",b,d/b);
    if (c>b)
        L=c;
    else (c<b);
        H=c;
    printf("The second  test score is: %.f\n",H);
    printf("The highest test score is: %.f\n",H);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unreadable. Format & Indent properly.

Answer (score 1):

You get what you ask for:

```
printf("The second  test score is: %.f\n",H);
printf("The highest test score is: %.f\n",H);
```

That's `H` in both lines. **That's what you get for cut-n-paste programming :-)**

There's also the broken `if/else` at the end. As it stands currently, your program only ever sets either `H` or `L`, never both. This must also be fixed to provide correct results.

I've said this a million times already on Stackoverflow, and will do it again:

> Not testing the return value from `scanf` is a sure recipe for surprises.

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code correctly, it will become evident that you have an extraneous `;` here

```
else (c < b);
```

the next block is being executed whether or not this condition is true, also it's incorrect syntax, it should be

```
else if (c < b)
    H = c;
```

Finally, you print `H` in both `printf()` statements, so I don't know what were you expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The computation is all wrong:

```
if (c > b)
    L = c;
else (c < b);
H = c;
```

You have to compute L and H inside the loop, because you're not recording the grades. You have to compare each grade with the previous L / H value to see if it's the new low / high.

Something like that:

```
float H = -1, L = -1;
...
for (a = 1 ; a <= b ; a++)
{
    ...

    if( L < 0 || c <= L ) {
        L = c; // the worst grade yet
    }
    if( H < 0 || c >= L ) {
        H = c; // the best grade yet
    }
}
```

And of course you have to actually print the values, here you're printing H twice.